# Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException'

Tags: mongodb, exception, connection

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 
'Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Permission denied' in 
/var/www/html/test.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/test.php(8): 
MongoClient->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/test.php 
on line 8
```

Hi Mongo experts...

I am a developer wanting to try out MongoDB. So installed centoOS 6.5 64bit in a test machine (Dell E520 Intel Dual Core 4GB Ram), installed PHP (Apache was already present).

Then installed MongoDB (yum install mongo-10gen mongo-10gen-server), then installed "pecl install mongo" (install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mongo-1.4.5), added extension=mongo.so to php.ini.

To install pecl, I installed few other things like C++ compiler & php-pear. php5-dev & php5-cli was not available in yum so installed php-devel & php-cli (installed versions are php-devel-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 & php-cli-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64

I turned off iptables firewall. Ran mongo --host localhost:27017 from shell & connected without problems

```
[root@localhost ~]# mongo --host localhost:27017
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: localhost:27017/test
>
```

These are the contents of test.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

// connect
$m = new MongoClient();
//$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");

// select a database
$db = $m->comedy;

// select a collection (analogous to a relational database's table)
$collection = $db->cartoons;

// add a record
$document = array( "title" => "Calvin and Hobbes", "author" => "Bill Watterson" );
$collection->insert($document);

// add another record, with a different "shape"
$document = array( "title" => "XKCD", "online" => true );
$collection->insert($document);

// find everything in the collection
$cursor = $collection->find();

// iterate through the results
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    echo $document["title"] . "\n";
}
?>
```

As you can see I have tried both 
$m = new MongoClient(); & $m = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");

But I am getting the same error. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you have setup authentication with MongoDB. Perhaps RedHat's package does that by default?

Comment: I am not sure how I have setup authentication & how to test it without it... can you tell me how to rewrite the code to work with MongoDB?

Comment: Your mongod instance could still be configured with authentication enabled, even though you were able to connect to it above. To verify if it is enabled, try running a test query on your cartoons collection. It should throw an error if you have not authenticated your session in the mongo shell.  To turn off authentication, you'll need to restart your mongod instance. You should check your mongod.cfg file to see if it enables authentication with the auth=true option.

Comment: In mongod.conf I found both auth=true & noauth=true were commented. I uncommented the noauth, restarted mongod... same result. Then commented noauth & uncommented auth, still same results.

Comment: Hm, maybe your php isn't allowed to connect to sockets? Try to connect to a locally running `netcat` using php's `fopen()` or try to issue a simple HTTP GET request. Is there a debugger for PHP that can break where the exception is actually thrown? That'd be a lot easier than guessing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem is documented at https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.fedora

Red Hat,Fedora and CentOS:

The default Apache settings on these systems do not let requests make network connections, meaning that the driver will get "Permission denied" errors when it tries to connect to the database. If you run into this, try running:

$ /usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

Then restart Apache. (This issue has also occurred with SELinux.)

Thanks for all your support!

Hope this thread helps someone from going in circles!

Comment: This answer is absolutely spot-on. Thought I'd mention as well that until I was doing a try and catch block to show errors, the screen simply was blank.  Once I echoed out $e->getMessage() I saw that the server was getting permission denied to Mongo.