# Upgrade to PyMongo 3.0 Resulting in ServerSelectionTimeoutError

Tags: python, mongodb, nginx, pymongo, uwsgi

I recently upgraded a Bottle + uWSGI + Nginx application to MongoDB 3.0.2. It was working fine with PyMongo 2.8, but today I upgraded to PyMongo 3.0 by running following command:

```
pip install --upgrade pymongo
```

I haven't done any other changes to the code, but now I keep getting the following error.

```
File "/pymongo/cursor.py", line 968, in __next__ if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
File "/pymongo/cursor.py", line 905, in _refresh self.__read_preference))
File "/pymongo/cursor.py", line 812, in __send_message **kwargs)
File "/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 716, in _send_message_with_response server = topology.select_server(selector)
File "/pymongo/topology.py", line 113, in select_server server_selection_timeout))
File "/pymongo/topology.py", line 93, in select_servers self._error_message(selector))
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No servers found yet
```

The function I use to connect to the database is the following:

```
def connect_db(db_name):
    global db
    host = "localhost"
    port = 27017
    connection = pymongo.MongoClient(host=host, port=port)
    db = connection[db_name]
```

I have restarted all the servers. The static pages work fine, but any page that tries to reach the database hangs and throws the error above. However, if I go to a `mongo` shell or a Python shell and query the MongoDB server, it works fine.

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> host = "localhost"
>>> port = 27017
>>> connection = pymongo.MongoClient(host=host, port=port)
>>> db = connection[test]
>>> db.test.insert_one({"test": True});
<pymongo.results.InsertOneResult object at 0x7fc43b8efc80>
```

It seems like only my application cannot find the MongoDB server. Note that I am using a Virtual Environment in case that would affect the situation in any way. Also, if I downgrade back to PyMongo 2.8, everything works fine.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, except that if you can connect with a Python shell but not from your application then that's really weird and suggests it's not a driver issue. Your configuration looks fine to me, it should work the same in PyMongo 2.8 and 3.0. I'll keep an eye on this question.

Comment: Thanks. I've downgraded back to PyMongo 2.8 for the moment, but will try  again.

Comment: @JuanCarlosFarah thanks for the pointer - I've also downgraded to 2.8 and fixed my problem. Any news on a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the same issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030307/why-is-pymongo-3-giving-serverselectiontimeouterror), and this [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-961). However I tried setting connect=False in the MongoClient() creation as suggested there to no avail. Currently the only solution that seems to work across the board is to downgrade to 2.8 (`pip install pymongo==2.8`)

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was surprising; **I entered this at the Bash prompt**:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
sudo service httpd restart
```

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20978569/1789466).  It turned out to be an Apache permissions issue.

---

Note: I'm running PyMongo 3.0, Python 2.6, and Mongo 2.4 on CentOS 6.6.  I got a marginally different error, but it was in the same line of PyMongo.  This was the end of my stack trace:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 93, in select_servers
    self._error_message(selector))
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: This didn't work for me (same error as OP). I also found that downgrading to 2.8 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030307/why-is-pymongo-3-giving-serverselectiontimeouterror).

The workaround to avoid triggering the bug works well (pass **connect=False** when creating instances of MongoClient).
There will be a clearer warning in pymongo version 3.0.4. and hopefully a fix in the next versions.

Answer (score -1):

Could this be related to [this critical PyMomongo 3.0 bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-898) when using mongos? If so, they pushed a fix on master branch (see [this commit](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/commit/81549e0608334c5f71461593680905a61ba5c3df).)

Comment: Not relevant. That bug only manifests when there are multiple hostnames in his connection string; he just uses one hostname. Also, the symptom is OperationFailure, not ServerSelectionTimeoutError.

Comment: I'm not using a `mongos`, so it wouldn't be related to this.

Answer (score -1):

**EDITED:**

Did you check your mongodb log file? I think that I had the same problem than you.

I found the following problem in /var/log/mongodb:

```
[initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
It seems I have no enough free disk in my VM so my mongodb it wasn't running on my machine.
```

In the following post is the solution for this error: [Why getting error mongod dead but subsys locked and Insufficient free space for journal files on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584393/why-getting-error-mongod-dead-but-subsys-locked-and-insufficient-free-space-for)

Now it seems that my problem was solved. Maybe you have the same error and you need to use smallfiles in order to work.

Best regards.