# Update with pull in MongoDB 3.2.5 matching but not modifying document

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, ubuntu-16.04

I am getting a 500 error on a `getJSON` request which maps to a `Python 2.7` function containing a MongoDB `update` with `$pull`.

Last error seen with `sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` is:

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 1721:tid 140612911712000] 
[client 127.0.0.1:59078] 
KeyError: 'nModified', referer: http://localhost/control_room
```

The Python logic that deals with this particular key is an `update` with `$pull`:

```
update_with_pull = collection.update({"user_email":user_email,"top_level.year":entry_year,"top_level.month":entry_month}, { "$pull": {dynamic_nested_key: {"timestamp":entry_timestamp}}})
```

The conditional after this is trying to catch if a document has been modified or not with:

```
if update_with_pull['nModified'] == 1:
  #do stuff
```

I tested the same operation in the mongo shell and it returned:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

So it seems to be matching the query but not doing any modifications.

To further troubleshoot, the `entry_timestamp` value which is used in the `$pull` section above is consistent in the database and the function (ie they are both strings with the same characters).

Some ideas:

- I've just moved the application from a `2.6.11` to a `3.2.5` MongoDB environment, which may be causing the problem, but, if so, I haven't been able to ascertain how yet.
- The syntax for `$pull` has changed in `3.2.5`?
- There are permission issues on the collection which are preventing modification?
- I'm running `pymongo 2.6.2` in `virtualenv` - perhaps it has some incompatibilities with MongoDB `3.2.5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Upgrading to `pymongo 3.2.2` causes error:

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No servers found yet
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31194981/1063287

However, I upgraded to `pymongo 2.8`, restarted apache and the problem seems to be resolved.