# Access Back4App mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, back4app

I'm trying to access my back4app app mongodb directly from a python script:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://admin:AAA@mongodb4.back4app.com:27017/BBB?ssl=true")
```

And I see that it connects but can't go further and figure out db name and collection names. Appreciate any help.

Comment: The same problem here. Sometimes it works, sometimes - doesn't. All the official documentation says is "You can connect to it at anytime using any MongoClient and make a dump of it and restore this dump wherever you want." -- and no information on how to actually do it.

Comment: This might be related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030307/why-is-pymongo-3-giving-serverselectiontimeouterror/31194981#31194981

Comment: Because of connect=False or not, it started working again.

Answer (score 2):

The db name is "BBB"

In order to get the collections, try:

```
db = client['BBB']
cols = db.collection_names()
for col in cols:
  print col
```

Instead of accessing the database directly you can also try a python SDK (not official), like this:
https://github.com/milesrichardson/ParsePy