# Django not able to run manage.py

Tags: python, django, djongo

I'm not able to run my Django server in local. I'm trying to setting my **djongo** database instead of default **sqlite3** .db

Here I followed the below URL for djongo[djongo on python](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/integrating-django-with-mongodb/) set up

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fb554b61bf8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 442, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 209, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 61, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 44, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 56, in table_names
    return get_names(cursor)
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 51, in get_names
    return sorted(ti.name for ti in self.get_table_list(cursor)
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/introspection.py", line 34, in get_table_list
    for c in cursor.db_conn.collection_names(False)]
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 715, in collection_names
    nameOnly=True, **kws)]
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 674, in list_collections
    read_pref) as (sock_info, slave_okay):
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1099, in _socket_for_reads
    server = topology.select_server(read_preference)
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 224, in select_server
    address))
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 183, in select_servers
    selector, server_timeout, address)
  File "/home/iradmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 199, in _select_servers_loop
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Here I have included my setting.py for your references.

```
DATABASES = {
  'default' : {
    'ENGINE' : 'djongo',
    'NAME' : 'my_database'
  }
}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is PyMongo 3 giving ServerSelectionTimeoutError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030307/why-is-pymongo-3-giving-serverselectiontimeouterror)

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the `USER` and `PASSWORD` when making a connection to your database? Since the error is `connection refused`, you might need to include the credentials to your database settings such as the `USER` and `PASSWORD`.

For example,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE' : 'djongo',
        'NAME' : 'my_database',
        'USER' : 'db-username',
        'PASSWORD': 'db-password'
    }
}
```

If not, you can refer to the following [Pymongo keeps refusing the connection at 27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744147/pymongo-keeps-refusing-the-connection-at-27017)