# ServerSelectionTimeoutError Pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I'm trying out pymongo for the first time and I keep getting a ServerSelectionTimeoutError. When using mongo commandline to login I run a command as follows

```
$ mongo-3.0 --ssl test.net:27080/db_qa --sslAllowInvalidCertificates -u content -p
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.12
Enter password:
```

and I'm able to connect fine but with pymongo I get the error

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: test.net:27080: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

My code is as follows

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://content:<password>@test.net:27080/db_qa')
client.server_info()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your connection string is missing the options that your shell command line provides, namely `ssl` and option to allow invalid certificate.

You could add `?ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE` after the database name in the string you are passing to `MongoClient` or see other options for certificate handling on [MongoClient](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html) page (scroll to "SSL configuration" section)

Answer (score 3):

So what worked for me was my refreshing my current IP which changed under the "setup connection security" tab

Answer (score 0):

I report my experience in which based on:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/troubleshoot-connection/#connection-string-issues

```
username = quote_plus('<username>')
password = quote_plus('<password>')
cluster = '<clusterName>'
authSource = '<authSource>'
authMechanism = '<authMechanism>'
uri = 'mongodb+srv://' + username + ':' + password + '@' + cluster + '/?authSource=' + authSource + '&authMechanism=' + authMechanism
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
client.server_info()
```

Basically adding `+srv` to the connection string seems to be using SSL implicitly.