# Flask app unable to query data from mongodb using mongoengine in a dockerized setup

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, mongoengine

I am running a website application and am using Flask which queries a mongodb database using mongoengine. Am getting an error when the application tries to query the database.

I have mongodb installed in one of the containers and I can connect to it successfully.

```
mongodb: 2019-09-06T03:45:11.801+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 172.20.0.3:43918 conn1: { driver: { name: "PyMongo", version: "3.9.0" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "x86_64", version: "3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64" }, platform: "CPython 3.7.2.final.0" }
```

Docker Setup

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  portfolio:
    build: ./portfolio
    container_name: portfolio
    restart: always
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=portfolio
    expose:
      - 8080
    links:
      - mongodb

  admin:
    build: ./admin
    container_name: admin
    restart: always
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=admin
    expose:
      - 8089
    links:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    depends_on:
      - portfolio
      - admin
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Python setup:

```
from flask import Flask
from mongoengine import connect
app = Flask(__name__)
connect('spees_db', host='mongodb://mongodb:27017/spees_db')
```

## Error occurs when I do

```
email_ex = User.objects(email=email).first()
```

Error stack:

```
nginx        | 102.140.206.140 - - [06/Sep/2019:03:53:09 +0000] "GET /register HTTP/1.1" 200 4145 "http://admin.shemoirere.com/login?next=%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
 [pid: 13|app: 0|req: 4/5] 102.140.206.140 () {44 vars in 967 bytes} [Fri Sep  6 03:53:09 2019] GET /register => generated 4145 bytes in 10 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 4 headers in 192 bytes (1 switches on core 1)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
     response = self.handle_exception(e)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
     raise value
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
     raise value
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.dispatch_request()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
   File "./admin/views.py", line 37, in do_register
     email_ex = User.objects(email=email).first()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/manager.py", line 37, in __get__
     queryset = queryset_class(owner, owner._get_collection())
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 207, in _get_collection
     db.client.is_primary:
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1006, in is_primary
     return self._server_property('is_writable')
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 831, in _server_property
     writable_server_selector)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 231, in select_server
nginx        | 2019/09/06 03:53:50 [error] 6#6: *5 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 102.140.206.140, server: admin.shemoirere.com, request: "POST /register HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://172.20.0.4:8089", host: "admin.shemoirere.com", referrer: "http://admin.shemoirere.com/register"
nginx        | 102.140.206.140 - - [06/Sep/2019:03:53:50 +0000] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://admin.shemoirere.com/register" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
     address))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 189, in select_servers
     selector, server_timeout, address)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 205, in _select_servers_loop
     self._error_message(selector))
 pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No servers found yet
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030307/why-is-pymongo-3-giving-serverselectiontimeouterror I do not know if that is related since the post is a little bit old ..

Comment: Hey LinPy, I tried that solution before but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: The app works well on pages that don't connect to the database. The login page opens but on trying to do the actual login it brings the error. Nginx to app is okay but app to Mongo is not.

Comment: Are you this isn't a docker-compose related issue? There can be many, e.g. is MongoDB up and running when you try to query it, do you rebuild your containers after code change? Also, don't use `links`, it's deprecated.

Comment: Remove link, container_name, and expose from your compose file- they don't do what you hope, and change the default behavior in some cases.

Comment: Hey Dusan, Mongodb is up. I've included a log that confirms a connection is received. I do rebuild the containers on core changes too. I changed docker compose too, still

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played around with your repo and figured out your issue. This is your wsgi config-

[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = run.py
callable = app
socket = :8089
processes = 4
threads = 2
master = true
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true

The problem is in the `processes` argument. uwsgi launches a master process and then uses fork() to spawn workers. You were doing your `connect` during the initial startup- so the connection lived in your master process, while your children were getting a bad copy. You can actually see the log on mongo when the connection happens... just 1! pymongo specifically calls out fork() as being unsafe with a connection.

The easiest fix for this is to add `lazy-apps = true` to the end of that wsgi file. The system works as intended then. You can also set up your app to avoid actually calling `connect` until the first time it is needed (probably the before first request hook?)

https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.9.0/faq.html#is-pymongo-fork-safe

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'll try that and get back to you

Comment: Could you check it cause it seems to just bring the same. https://github.com/Oirere-Jr/portfolio_nginx.git

Comment: I figured out your issue-

Comment: It actually worked. Whoa!! Thank you so much for your time and solution.