# Flask-PyMongo SSL Handshake Issue

Tags: python, mongodb, ssl, flask, tls1.2

I have an issue connecting to my AWS MongoDB cluster. Whenever I try to insert some data it goes to timeout. Please check the error below.

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: SSL handshake failed: ajans0-shard-00-01-1mosu.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645),SSL handshake failed: ajans0-shard-00-02-1mosu.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645),SSL handshake failed: ajans0-shard-00-00-1mosu.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645) 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jun/2020 12:09:18] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

If Anyone faced this issue please advise me some solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030307/why-is-pymongo-3-giving-serverselectiontimeouterror

Comment: Not really I think I have different issue here but thank you anyway